# How to prove that the characteristic function of $n \bar{X}^2$ converges to that of chi square

Tags: probability, probability-limit-theorems, characteristic-functions, chi-squared

Let $X_i$ be *iid* random variables with $E[X_1] = 0$ and $E[X_1^2] = \sigma^2$. I wonder how to show that the characteristic function of $n \bar{X}^2$ converges to that of $\sigma^2 Y$, where $Y$ is a random variable with the $\chi^2_{(1)}$ distribution, *directly*, i.e., without using the continuous mapping theorem and the fact that convergence in distribution implies the convergence of characteristic functions.

The problem is similar to how the central limit theorem is proved, where we evaluate the characteristic function of $\sqrt{n} \bar{X}$ and establish that it converges to $\exp( - \sigma^2 t^2 / 2)$, the characteristic function of $N(0, \sigma^2)$, as $n \to \infty$. I want to do the same for the characteristic function of $n \bar{X}^2$. However, unlike in the proof of the central limit theorem, apparently I cannot break $n \bar{X}^2$ into independent terms. Also, the expression of the characteristic function of $\sigma^2 Y$, where $Y$ has $\chi^2_{(1)}$ distribution, is considerably more complex, being equal to $(1 - 2 i \sigma^2 t)^{-1/2}$. How does one deal with such an expression? Or, would it be prudent to try to evaluate the square of the characteristic function of $n \bar{X}^2$ and show that it converges to $(1 - 2 i \sigma^2 t)^{-1} = (1 + 2 i \sigma^2 t) / (1 + 4 \sigma^4 t^2)$? I have been unable to proceed.

Comment: What about second order delta method? Have you considered this approach?

Comment: @MatthewH. I can't use the central limit theorem and infer from there, I have to explicitly evaluate the characteristic function of $n \bar{X}^2$ and show its convergence. Delta method would use the convergence in distribution of $\bar{X}$.

Comment: Sorry I misread the problem. I thought you couldn't use characteristics functions, my bad

Comment: Are you sure we can do it without a fourth-moment bound?

Comment: @user10354138 using the central limit theorem, the continuous mapping theorem and then the Levy continuity theorem it follows that the characteristic function of $n \bar{X}$ converges to that of the chi square, without any assumption on the fourth moment. I want to show the same thing directly, using the expressions of the characteristic functions only.

Comment: @user10354138 Although the convergence of characteristic functions would happen without any assumption on the fourth moment, I am wondering if it is possible and easier to derive that with an assumption of bound on the fourth moment.